# How can I search Google for number ranges that use the M and K number abbreviation?

Tags: search, google-search, search-engine

My goal is to search Google for instagram profiles that have a certain amount of followers. Filtering down to profiles only is easy but the hard part is making google understand the number abbreviation of M and K. For example "13M Followers" or "307K Followers" as you can see here for example

```
https://www.instagram.com/sow_much_more/
```

I've experimented with the range and wildcard features but because you can't include a trailing character like "100..200K" I can't get the desired results.

For example

```
site:instagram.com "100..200" "K followers" intitle:"instagram photos"
```

Provides me with profiles which may have the desired number of followers but also maybe have 100..200 on the page's text that isn't a follow count.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Use the [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) and follow the field help next to each input box.

---

1. The numeric range should not be enclosed in double-quotes.
2. Don't use M or K. Write the complete number.

You might try:

```
site:instagram.com 100000..200000 followers intitle:"instagram photos"
```

Comment: I'm getting good enough results. Please edit your question to clarify what are getting and what are you expecting.

Comment: When I use the query above I would be expecting profiles with followers in the range of 100000 to 200000. However the first three results are 2 followers, 499,000 followers and 265,000 followers.

Comment: I got different results. It's normal that the results shown to different users are different, that is why I suggested you edit your question, so you could add enough details so others might better understand your context.